# No data in csv after writing through python code

Tags: python-2.7, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to write my dataset generated in python to a csv file.

am writing the following code :

```
with open("list.csv", "wb") as f:
      writer = csv.writer(f)
      writer.writerows(results)
```

It gives no error and also my results set has shows data when i print it but when i open the csv file i get a blank document with no data.

Comment: use with open("list.csv", "w") as f:

Comment: @Nabin it dint help..

Comment: @BurhanKhalid its a list

Comment: @vivek27 your csv file is in the same directory where your python file is..

Comment: @Nabin yes both are in same directory.

Comment: @vivek27 did you see my comment on my answer? and did you try as mentioned there?

Comment: @Nabin it works if list is pre-defined but am using a list of data scraped from a website.

Comment: send me output of "print results"

Comment: for result in results:
     print result

@vivek27

Comment: @Nabin tried printing results. It has data in it.

Comment: Let me know the whole code...

Comment: Post the bit of code that is generating `results`; the problem is there and not with this snippet you pasted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv

mylist = ['yo','man','why','wont','it','work']
with open('test.csv', 'w') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp)
    a.writerows(mylist)
```

Comment: still no data in the file.

Comment: import csv and try again